# TypeError: this.props.produtos is null on a React Filter project?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I've been working on a ecommerce project, there i pass some products (produtos) via Redux to a products page, but i've been trying to filter it using .filter() and it keeps giving me this error "TypeError: this.props.produtos is null". If i don't use the Filter(), my products appears correctly, but without the filtering.

here's the code (you can find the .filter right after the render()

```
class Produtos extends Component {

    loadProdutosHandler() {
        if (!this.props.produtos) {
            developmentServer.get('jogos')
                .then(response => {
                    this.props.updateProdutosHandler(response.data.data);
                });
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.loadProdutosHandler();
    }

    componentDidUpdate() {
        this.loadProdutosHandler();
    }

    produtoClickedHandler = (id) => {
        if (this.props.showSidebar) {
            this.props.sidebarChangedHandler(false);
        }

        this.props.history.replace({ pathname: this.props.match.url + '/' + id });
    }

    render() {


        const key = 'xbox';
        let produtos = <Loader />;

        if (this.props.produtos.filter(produtos => 
            this.props.produtos.map(produtos => this.props.produtos.plataforma))
        )
         {
            produtos =
                <div className={classes.Produtos}>
                <Banner src={img} />
                    <div className={classes.Formata}>
                        <SideBar />
                        <section className={classes.SectionProduto}>
                            <ListaCatalogo produtos={this.props.produtos}
                                url={this.props.match.url}
                                clicked={this.produtoClickedHandler} />
                        </section>
                    </div>
                </div>
        }

        return produtos;
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        showSidebar: state.layoutRdc.showSidebar,
        produtos: state.produtosRdc.produtos
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        sidebarChangedHandler: (value) => dispatch(actionCreators.showSidebar(value)),
        updateProdutosHandler: (value) => dispatch(actionCreators.updateProdutos(value))
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Produtos);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe `produtos` is null while the first rendering of the your view! Look where you define your `produtosRdc` and if `produtos` default value is `null` replace it with `[]`.

Comment: thanks for the help bro! At first it worked, but the products redux stopped working (none of the products inside our API appeared). Im trying to think how can i fix that using your solution now...